# swift2.3: sqlite insert does'n worked

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have two table in the SQLite

And I want insert data to "table:buy" from "table:material"

above is my sqlite datas

"material table" here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiCEq.jpg

And this is "buy table" :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLP3p.jpg

It's empty because I want insert data to it

```
 var statement = COpaquePointer()
```

func materialLoadData() {

```
   let db_path = "/Users/huangpinquan/Desktop/Recipes/Recipes/Recipes.sqlite"

    var db = COpaquePointer()
    let status = sqlite3_open(db_path,&db)

    if (status == SQLITE_OK) {

        print("Open the sqlite success!\n")
    }else {
        print("Open the sqlite failed!\n")
    }

var sql : String?
  sql = "INSERT INTO buy(material,amount) select material, amount From materials WHERE name = '巧克力手工餅乾' "

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db , sql!, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            print("insert success")
 } else {
             print("insert faild")
}
```

}

Comment: What print statements do you see? Use `sqlite3_errmsg` to log errors when needed.

Comment: Where's your call to `sqlite3_step`, `sqlite3_finalize`, and `sqlite3_close`?

Comment: [link](https://gist.github.com/huangharry/2c8f806903a7907668d36a282843d55a) This is my sqliet whole cdoe, it seems I don't have `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_close` but only have `sqlite3_close`

Comment: What about using a SQLite swift wrapper such as http://github.com/groue/GRDB.swift ? It supports Swift 2.3, and will follow you when you eventually migrate to Swift 3.